# Is there a way to show a changing dataframe in real time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, user-interface, web-scraping

I am **scraping** data from https://www.bseindia.com/markets/PublicIssues/BSEBidDetails_ofs.aspx?flag=NR&Scripcode=541729. Every 10 seconds the data changes. So I have made a timer for the script to run. At the start of each iteration it re initializes the pandas dataframe and scrapes the website and adds data to the dataframe. Is there a way I can Visulise this data in a static window?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import time
url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/markets/PublicIssues/BSEBidDetails_ofs.aspx?flag=NRScripcode=541729'
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
bseobj=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price Interval','qNumber of bids','qConfirmed','qYet to be confirmed','qTotal','Confirmed','Yet to be confirmed','Total'])
while True:
   i=0
   r=[]
   lr=[]    
   webpage = urlopen(req).read()
   page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
   table=page_soup.find_all("table")

   for row in table[1]:
       for column in row.find_all("td",{"class":"body_text_table"},{"bgcolor":"#FFFFFF"}):
            val=column.get_text()
            val=val.replace(',','')
            chk=val.replace('.','')
            if chk.isdigit():
                r.append(float(val))
            elif val=="":
                r.append(0)
            else:
                r.append(val)
            
        lr.append(r)
        r=[]
    for i in range(2,len(lr)-2):
        bseobj=bseobj.append({'Price Interval':lr[i][0],'qNumber of bids':lr[i][1],'qConfirmed':lr[i][2],'qYet to be confirmed':lr[i][3],'qTotal':lr[i][4],'Confirmed':lr[i][5],'Yet to be confirmed':lr[i][6],'Total':lr[i][7]},ignore_index=True)
    print(bseobj)
    bseobj=bseobj.iloc[0:0]
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: to solve this, I would create use multiprocessing, put the sscraper in one process, and the program that reads the dataframe in another process. I would then share the data between these two processes using `multiprocessing.namespace`.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to use python to that? If not, can you provide your code for reading/interacting with the dataframe?

Comment: That is smart. I'll check on that. I don't have an idea but have an intuition about it. This is the code itself. Thank you @simic0de